# tm custom removePunctuation except hashtag

Tags: r, customization, text-processing, tm, punctuation

I have a Corpus of tweets from twitter. I clean this corpus (removeWords, tolower, delete URls) and finally also want to remove punctuation.

Here is my code:

```
tweetCorpus <- tm_map(tweetCorpus, removePunctuation, preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE)
```

The problem now is, that by doing so I also loose the hashtag (#). Is there a way to remove punctuation with tm_map but remain the hashtag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could adapt the existing removePunctuation to suit your needs. For example

```
removeMostPunctuation<-
function (x, preserve_intra_word_dashes = FALSE) 
{
    rmpunct <- function(x) {
        x <- gsub("#", "\002", x)
        x <- gsub("[[:punct:]]+", "", x)
        gsub("\002", "#", x, fixed = TRUE)
    }
    if (preserve_intra_word_dashes) { 
        x <- gsub("(\\w)-(\\w)", "\\1\001\\2", x)
        x <- rmpunct(x)
        gsub("\001", "-", x, fixed = TRUE)
    } else {
        rmpunct(x)
    }
}
```

Which will give you

```
removeMostPunctuation("hello #hastag @money yeah!! o.k.")
# [1] "hello #hastag money yeah ok"
```

and when you use it with tm_map, but sure to wrap it in `content_transformer()`

```
tweetCorpus <- tm_map(tweetCorpus, content_transformer(removeMostPunctuation),
    preserve_intra_word_dashes = TRUE)
```

Comment: This was pretty cryptic with the extra steps to use sentinels \001,\002 to temporarily protect '#','-' from removal. Did you prefer not to simply expand `[[:punct:]]` without those symbols, to avoid breaking Unicode punctuation?

Answer (score 8):

The **qdap** package that I maintain has the `strip` function to handle this where you can specify characters not to strip:

```
library(qdap)

strip("hello #hastag @money yeah!! o.k.", char.keep="#")
```

Here it is applied to a `Corpus`:

```
library(tm)

tweetCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource("hello #hastag @money yeah!! o.k."))
tm_map(tweetCorpus, content_transformer(strip), char.keep="#")
```

Also **qdap** has the `sub_holder` function that does essentially what Mr. Flick's `removeMostPunctuation` function does if that's useful

```
removeMostPunctuation <- function(text, keep = "#") {
    m <- sub_holder(keep, text)
    m$unhold(strip(m$output))
}

removeMostPunctuation("hello #hastag @money yeah!! o.k.")

## "hello #hastag money yeah ok"
```